# Math mode inside underbrace text

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, underbrace

**Problem:**

Trying to activate math mode inside underbrace text but I receive errors telling me that I am not allowed. I have managed to solve this with `\[` and `\]` but the equation shifts to the center of the page despite using `\noindent`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\noindent $(a \pm b)^2 = (a \pm b)(a \pm b) = a \cdot a \pm a \cdot b \pm \underbrace{b \cdot a}_\text{a \cdot b} + b \cdot b = a^2 \pm 2ab + b^2$

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

Get math mode to work inside underbrace text while keeping the overall text aligned to the left.

Comment: Although the accepted answer is a simpler solution, `\[ \]` is display mode, and you can instead use `\( \)` for inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory you could use `$...$` to have math mode inside `\text{...}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\noindent $(a \pm b)^2 = (a \pm b)(a \pm b) = a \cdot a \pm a \cdot b \pm \underbrace{b \cdot a}_\text{$a \cdot b$} + b \cdot b = a^2 \pm 2ab + b^2$

\end{document}
```

But why do you use `\text{...}` for math? Just remove it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\noindent $(a \pm b)^2 = (a \pm b)(a \pm b) = a \cdot a \pm a \cdot b \pm \underbrace{b \cdot a}_{a \cdot b} + b \cdot b = a^2 \pm 2ab + b^2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is embarrassing - I certainly do not know why I had it in my mind that I `had` to use `\text` to get underbrace to work.