# Curved Line Under Number (not sure what it's called)

Tags: braces, underbrace

How would I make something like this in Latex?
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure it's literally a duplicate, but [Tex.SE Question 30090](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30090/how-can-i-get-text-underneath-an-underbrace) and [Tex.SE Question 498790](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498780/math-mode-inside-underbrace-text?rq=1)  give you what you need.  In brief, `amsmath`'s `\underbrace` and similar commands type under-material in math mode, use `\text` for text mode.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `\underbrace` command or using `mathtools` the `\underbracket` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

You can try $1\!\underbrace{666\cdots6}_{m\textup{ 6's}}$ or $1\!\underbracket{666\cdots6}_{m\textup{ 6's}}$

\end{document}
```

If you want a round brace with the text through it, you can use the `abraces` package ([documentation here](https://ctan.org/pkg/abraces?lang=en)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{abraces}

\begin{document}

A special underbrace for $1\!\aunderbrace[l1@{\raisebox{-2pt}{\smash{\scriptsize\,$m$ 6's\,}}}1r]{666\cdots6}$.

\end{document}
```

Or if you want the text lower:

[image]

```
A special underbrace for $1\!\aunderbrace[l1@{\raisebox{-4pt}{\scriptsize\,$m$ 6's\,}}1r]{666\cdots6}$.
```